# Python library for rendering music notation

Tags: gratis, python, music, raspberry-pi

I was looking at [Python In Music](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) but I'm not sure whether any of listed libraries actually supports

- rendering of music notes
- export the result as a PNG

Background: I want to train children reading notes. To do so, I want to provide a Raspberry Pi 2B including a 400x320 display. The Raspberry is connected to a keyboard via MIDI. The children see the notes and have to play the correct tones. It's about reading notes, not about playing fluently, so the small display is sufficient.

Example 320x240 screen of the final result:

[image: Example screen]

I'm looking for a library that can generate the treble clef, lines, rhythm indicator and the notes.

Comment: Maybe the bC note was not an ideal example in this quick mockup.

Answer (score 7):

[LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/) is the go to for musical notation engraving - there are several python libraries that interface with it such as [Abjad](http://projectabjad.org/).

- Gratis - **Yes**
- python - **can be interfaced with**
- raspberry-pi - **Yes**
- output to pdf, ps or png

generate the:
 - treble clef, 
 - lines,
 - rhythm indicator
 - and the notes.
All of the above, using a text notation, and more such as cords, multiple parts, other notations, ect.

An example that I knocked up - *not musically sound I am sure*:

```
\language "english"
\relative c'' {
  \time 4/4
  cs2 es4 f4 ds4( g2) cs4 e4 bf( c4 fb2 g4) {af bs} e~
}
\addlyrics {
  Croak like a frog in a Lily-Pond! 
}
```

[image]

Some exampled from the website:

Fret board:
[image]

Gregorian
[image]

Complex Notation:
[image]

Comment: I think that is what I'm looking for. Unfortunately it does not install. Lilypond installed fine with `sudo apt-get install lilypond`, PIP installed also fine with `sudo apt-get install python-pip` but Abjed (`pip install abjad`) returns an error "Error:root:Error parsing". I'll try to fix it with Google magic

Comment: @ThomasWeller to globally install anything on Linux using `pip` you need `sudo pip install` _`xxxx`_ - personally I usually use `sudo pip install -U` _`xxxx`_ to ensure that dependent packages are updated as well. Alternatively use python viritualenv see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv